ImportError: cannot import name 'def_function' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (unknown location)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras.api import DTypePolicy
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.api import _tf_keras
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/_tf_keras/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.api._tf_keras import keras
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/_tf_keras/keras/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.api import activations
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/api/activations/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations import deserialize
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import activations
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/activations/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations.activations import elu
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/activations/activations.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import backend
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.dtypes import result_type
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.dtypes import result_type
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/dtypes.py", line 5, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.variables import standardize_dtype
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/variables.py", line 11, in <module>
    from keras.src.utils.module_utils import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src.utils.audio_dataset_utils import audio_dataset_from_directory
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/audio_dataset_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras.src.utils import dataset_utils
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/dataset_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.src import tree
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/tree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src.tree.tree_api import assert_same_structure
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/tree/tree_api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from keras.src.tree import optree_impl as tree_impl
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/tree/optree_impl.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.trackable.data_structures import ListWrapper
  File "/Users/ice/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/data_structures.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import def_function
ImportError: cannot import name 'def_function' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (unknown location)

I'm trying to install keras and encounter the same problem even after reinstalling TensorFlow. Tried reinstalling many times but same problem still prevails. Tried asking chatgpt but to no avail. Anyone have encountered this problem? Please send help!

Does this error occur during the install or when trying to run your script?  What method are you using to install? Conda? Pip? What versions of keras and tensorflow are you installing? What version of Python (I see 3.10, but is there an additional minor version?)

The issue might be due to incompatible versions or incorrect installation of tensorflow. Try reinstalling the tensorflow correctly by following this document to ensure a correct setup.
